# expected boolean value error in tcl and arrays

Tags: serial-port, tcl, dts

I've slowly progressing through my serialport tcl app but hit another wall.

I want to create an array of boolean values to iterate in a for loop.

In the for loop, DTR will send a serial output.

Below I have the following code:

```
set rs232 [open COM3: r]
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol {DTR 0}

array set values {
0   0
1   1
}

set n [array size values]

set x 0
for {set a 0} {$a <=15} {incr a} {
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol {DTR $values(0)}
wait 1000
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol {DTR $values(1)}
wait 1000
}
```

I run it and I get the error:

```
    expected boolean value but got "$values(0)"
```

Can anyone tell me why this is and how do I fix it?

Comment: That seems a clumsy way to encode "true" and "false". The valid Tcl boolean values are spelled out on the [Tcl_GetBoolean](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/GetInt.htm) man page -- **false** is any of 0, "false", "no", or "off"; **true** is any of 1, "true", "yes", or "on".

Comment: ok cheers Glenn, I've looked at TCL_GetBoolean page but it doesn't show an example I don't know how interp, src, boolPtr arguements are typed. You don't have an example do you please?

Comment: `set value "false"; if {$value} then {puts OK} else {puts No}` -- My first comment was mainly that `$values(0)` is a very verbose way to write `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This invocation:

```
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol {DTR $values(0)}
```

passes the value "DTR $values(0)" for `-ttycontrol` to `fconfigure`. The invocation

```
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol [list DTR $values(0)]
```

passes "DTR 0".

The braces prevent substitution of the variable, but the invocation of `list` enforces it.

Alternatively, you could use one of

```
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol "DTR $values(0)"
fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol [subst {DTR $values(0)}]
```

Comment: Thanks for that Peter much appreciated. I have tried adding list and it now works.

Comment: I am now trying this in a for loop and substituting the index value with i but it comes back with can't read "SHCP(i)": no such element in array. The code is: [code] for {set i 0} {i<=15} {incr i} {fconfigure $rs232 -ttycontrol [list DTR $SHCP(i)]} }

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Tcl syntax - take a look at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl10.html

Comment: @KennyBarber: `$SHCP(i)` is the value of the "i" member of the `SHCP` array. `$SHCP($i)` is the member of the array named by the *value of* "i". Do take a look at the tutorial @ColinMacLeod mentioned.

Comment: Colin, I have made the for loop, loop through i. I have another problem now so I'll make a new question